# jekyll: combine limit and where and reverse

Tags: jekyll

Using Jekyll i'd like to:

- iterate through all the pages
- where the page.path is not the current path
- where the page.categories contains "featured"
- reverse them(most recent first)
- limit 3

i'm having problems when getting all those filters together

```
{% assign posts = site.posts | reverse %}
{% for post in posts limit:3 %}
  {% if post.categories contains 'featured' and post.path != page.path %}
    {% include card.html post=post %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

right now the limit is not working properly because the inner `if` will prevent a few items from being rendered.

Comment: What is site.templates? How does it looks like?

Comment: @marcanuy sorry its the posts collection. nothing special about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign `0` to a `counter` variable before entering your loop. Don't set a limit on the loop, but instead set another condition on your `counter` being below your limit, and increment the `counter` using Liquid's `plus` filter every time you meet your criteria and output the card.

```
{% assign posts = site.posts | reverse %}
{% assign counter = 0 %}
{% for post in posts %}
  {% if counter < 3 and post.categories contains 'featured' and post.path != page.path %}
    {% include card.html post=post %}
    {% assign counter = counter | plus: 1 %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

#### A more complex example

I'm basing all of this on the looping I use myself. My condition is a little more complex: I check for any shared tag with the current page. I've included this as a further example below.

```
{% assign counter = 0 %}
{% for post in site.posts %}
    {% if counter < 4 %}
        {% if post.url != page.url %}
            {% assign isValid = false %}
            {% for page_tag in page.tags %}
                {% for post_tag in post.tags %}
                    {% if post_tag == page_tag %}
                        {% assign isValid = true %}
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
            {% if isValid %}
                {% include article_card.html %}
                {% assign counter = counter | plus: 1 %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

#### Why `where` fails

Although [Liquid has a `where` filter](https://www.siteleaf.com/blog/advanced-liquid-where/), it can only do exact comparisons, so you have to reinvent the wheel like this in order to achieve the `where`-like scenario for more complex conditions. This does make for a lot of looping through `site.posts`, but Jekyll being a preprocessor means the penalty of using a somewhat inefficient improvised `where`-type looping is only a compile-time concern, not a runtime one. Even so, to mitigate this cost as much as possible, I opt for having the `counter` condition be the first that Jekyll calculates.